# Nested linear layouts Vs Single relative layout

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am creating a layout which has two views in same line horizontally on top and below that all views are vertically arranged.I have read that its advisable to use linear layout wherever possible.However in this case if I have to use linear layout then I need to create another Linear Layout inside parent Linear Layout to hold top two views with orientation horizontal and my parent layout will have orientation vertical which will contain all views.

Instead if i use relativelayout as parent layout then all views can be arrange in single parent layout without the need to create any child layout.

Which is a better approach-nested linear layouts or single relative layout?

Comment: Single RelativeLayout, obviously. Nesting layouts is bad for performances.

Comment: @Rotwang Is it possible to achieve the above requirements using single LinearLayout?

Comment: No, you can't. LinearLayouts either arrange the items horizontally **or** vertically.

Comment: You can try GridLayout

Comment: Can you show us the layout in MS Paint? Is this a root layout? What are the views in the top layout?

Comment: @Vivart but a GridLayout is even less performant than a ReletiveLayout.

Comment: from android docs.
Deep layouts - Layouts with too much nesting are bad for performance. Consider using flatter layouts such as RelativeLayout or GridLayout to improve performance.
here its not mentioned that which one is better but i think RelativeLayout takes two measure pass. So i think GridLayout's performance will be better.

Comment: @Vivart OK, it's not specified. But how many measures do you think a GridLayout would take? Not only the two required by a RelativeLayout, but also the ones needed to determine how to fit the different cells inside. Therefore (I **suppose** as a logical consequence), it's slower than a "simple" RelativeLayout.

Comment: "Not only the two required by a RelativeLayout" why it will take two required by RelativeLayout. GridLayout knows how many child views are there and what will be the position of them. i think it will measure in one pass only.

Comment: @Vivart Well, we're basing on suppositions, I guess. We have no real evidence of which one is faster.